# how to get image file type from ios gallery Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ios, gallery, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I want get the name of the image type like i selected `.png` ,`.gif` ...etc,I need to get the name of the selected from iOS gallery.For that i am using the following code snippet.

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
success:function(event)
{
var cropRect = event.cropRect;
    image = event.media;

    if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
    {

        var newImageName = new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";

        //var newImageName = new Date().getTime();

        var filename = Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + "/" + newImageName;
        Ti.App.Properties.setString("filename", filename);
        newImage = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(filename);

        newImage.write(image);
   }
```

through every file is converted to jpg format .I want get the what every file extension in gallery.